# Issue in automatic file uploading through Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-7

I'm facing some difficulties with file uploading control in selenium.

My code is working fine on windows 8 but when i run this code on windows 7. The program hangs for some time and then it gives exception.

below is my code which i'm using to select file in file upload control

```
IWebElement fileuploader = driver.FindElement(By.Name("uploadFile"));
fileuploader.SendKeys("C:\\temp\\file.txt");
```

- Code is written in C#.
- Exception:

  > The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
  >   http://localhost/xxxxxxxxxxx/value timed out after 60 seconds.
- OS: Windows 7
- Browser: Internet explorer 9

thanks in advance

Comment: quick qn: does it work when you do it manually?

Comment: yes,Its working when i do it manually @VinothS

Comment: Can you post your html plz?

Comment: <tr>
          <td width="15%" nowrap="">Upload txt file </td>
          <td width="85%" align="left">
         <input type="file" class="bdr" onkeypress="return false;" value="" name="uploadFile">
          </td>
        </tr>

Comment: interesting...could you change the timeout of the remotewebdriver and see?

Comment: I have already tried that, but no luck!!!!!!